# Graphs breaks on the left and bottom sides

Tags: graph, latex, gnuplot

I am working on gnuplot with bar-stacked. I tried to create an ideal size on graphs. any breaks on the left and the top of graph. I think it is not problems because my latex file can show perfect graph without any breaks. But when I tried run in other OS, it has error in latex. It can't handle the graphs. After I found the root cause of this, it is happen because I am use:

> font ",40"

So, latex can't process it and break on this graph. I guess it have related with my break in my *.eps files.

This is my data:

```
desc    is-1    is-2    is-3    is-4    is-5    is-6    is-7    is-8
A   37.01   24.80   28.39   2.65    3.70    1.10    2.20    0.14
B   58.16   22.19   9.95    3.06    3.32    3.32    0.00    0.00
C   40.46   18.72   18.49   6.45    14.27   1.04    0.33    0.24
D   30.29   31.59   22.39   9.69    1.30    2.37    1.57    0.80
E   35.41   15.88   24.71   14.67   7.18    1.52    0.32    0.32
F   29.91   30.36   18.29   9.46    8.29    1.26    1.89    0.54
Tot 37.41   22.61   21.76   7.71    7.66    1.52    0.99    0.34
```

This is my Gnuplot File:

```
set term pos eps font 20
set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border -1

set key reverse above Left width 3 height -2.5 font ",40" autotitle columnheader
set key outside top spacing 2.5 
set boxwidth 0.7
set format y "%.0f%%"
set yrange [0:100]
set size 0.9 , 2
set ytics out nomirror
#set offset -0.3,-0.6,0,0 

#label count
set label 1 "854" at 0,102 rotate by 90 font ",40"  
set label 2 "274" at 1,102  rotate by 90 font ",40"
set label 3 "1564" at 2,102 rotate by 90 font ",40"
set label 4 "740" at 3,102  rotate by 90 font ",40"
set label 5 "979" at 4,102  rotate by 90 font ",40"
set label 6 "204" at 5,102  rotate by 90 font ",40"
set label 7 "4625" at 6,102 rotate by 90 font ",40"

set xtics font ",40"
set ytics font ",40"

set bmargin 3
set xtics offset 0,-1,0

set notitle
set noylabel
set noxlabel
set border 3 lw 2
set output 'output.eps'
plot 'datafile' \
    using($2):xtic(1)   lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($3)           lt -1 fs pattern 2, \
''  using($4)           lt -1 fs pattern 5, \
''  using($5)           lt -1 fs pattern 9, \
''  using($6)           lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($7)           lt -1 fs pattern 7, \
''  using($8)           lt -1 fs pattern 3, \
''  using($5)           lt -1 fs pattern 4
```

This is my output:

[image]

I am guessing latex error because of Gnuplot Font, It will clear if the output in*.eps file show the perfect graph. Could you help me, what is wrong with my border gnuplot script? Thanks or any suggestion for my problems?

*ps: graphs looks good on Ubuntu 12.04 but break in mac os. Thanks Thanks Thanks

after I set lmargin =10:

[image]

Comment: @indi61 I suppose if you play around with `lmargin` and `tmargin` along with `key spacing`, then you should be able to put the graph in place!

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar Thanks for answer.
I have tried margin options. if we use lmargin it will sliding to left side and lmargin can't be negative value. I also tried to thinker using rmargin. The maximum as my image above. 

Could I resize the canvas? I expect the *.eps file show the graph without break.

Comment: Try this value: `set lmargin 10`

Comment: great @ZahaibAkhtar I play with `set key outside top spacing 2.5` and also `height -2.5` but the same. Are you sure only `set key`?

Comment: Okay I'm going to add an answer, but really these you can work out by playing around with the values, there is no magic trick here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the following:

```
set lmargin 10
set tmargin 15
```

These will just add a left margin and top margin to your plot so that you have enough space.

And changed this line:

```
set key reverse above Left width 3 height 1 font ",40" autotitle columnheader
```

I changed the height to a small positive number in the above